# Catch22 - HTML waiting for JS, JS waiting for HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie trying to write a JS/HTML report generator based on criteria which I submit in an HTML form. The plan eventually is to use PHP/mySQL to manipulate a database and return results but for now I'm just trying to build the HTML/CSS/JS and I've got stuck. I have attributed a JS function to a button in the `<body>` like so:

`<input type="button" id="reportButton" value="Generate Report" onclick="showCriteria()">`

I included a script in the `<head>` as follows:

`<script>var showCriteria = function(){ My JS code...}</script>`.

This function simply does some date manipulation and displays the result in a div on the same page like so:

`document.getElementById("endDate").innerHTML = "to "+endDay+" "+endMonthName+" "+endYear;`

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. So I searched the forum and discovered that this can sometimes be caused by not waiting for the window to load. So I wrapped the script as follows:

`<script>
window.onload = function()
    var showCriteria = function(){ My JS code...}`

That solved the initial error but I then get `Uncaught ReferenceError: showCriteria is not defined`

It seems like I'm in a Catch22. I get the first error because the script is running before the window has loaded. I fix that by waiting for the window to load only to find that the HTML is waiting for my script to define my JS function.

Any advice gratefully received.

[Report Generator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoMSE.png)

[Window.load script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP8KO.png)

Comment: Unless you are causing the button click event handler to fire before the page is loaded (obviously unlikely) then the problem is not that the DOM is not loaded.  Does the element actually have the attribute `id="endDate"`?

Comment: By adding `window.onload` you've taken the `showCriteria` function out of the global scope. You haven't fixed the previous error, you just created another one.

Comment: Yes - the div element has the correct id.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got the solution. At least you've got all the right elements.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('reportButton').addEventListener('click', showCriteria);
};
```

This will make it so the button does not function until the page is ready.

You also need to remove the **onclick** from the button.

Comment: Don't forget the onclick needs to be removed with this solution.

Comment: Tried that and no longer get the error but the showCriteria function doesn't appear to be working. Nothing is displaying in the endDate div (yes I do have that correctly referenced) and the button is locking in the hover/focus mode suggesting that the code has halted when I clicked (although I don't get any error message in my Chrome console). I'd like to show you the code but it seems there's some limit to the number of characters in my reply - is that correct? Do I have to start a new question to show you the code?

Comment: You can update your question with additional information.

Comment: Try replacing "showCriteria" in addEventListener with "function(){alert('hello world!')}".

Comment: Very strange . I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`  error. Here's the code   `<script>window.onload = function() {
function(){alert('hello world!')}
document.getElementById('reportButton').addEventListener('click', showCriteria);</script>`  I'll put a screenshot in the main body of my question if that helps.

Comment: Just to be clear .. the "Hello World" alert doesn't appear. Very weird.

Comment: Use: <script>window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('reportButton').addEventListener('click', function(){alert('hello world!')});</script>

Comment: I'm trying to isolate the DOM event from your showCriteria function.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the `showCriteria` function inside `window.onload`, please make sure it is accessible by the `DOM`, i.e. `window.showCriteria`.

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
  window.showCriteria = function(){ My JS code...}
...
```

Beside using `onclick` on html, you can use add listener to listen the click event on that element.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('reportButton').addEventListener('click', showCriteria);
};
```

Comment: Tried `window.showCriteria = function(){ My JS code...}` but I get the same `Uncaught ReferenceError: showCriteria is not defined` error.

Comment: There is old best practice to put the `<script>` tag after the body since the DOM was already loaded when the script is ready. Beside your question, I said it was old because now we have html5 support `async / defer` attribute. FYI, http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html,

Comment: Tried putting `<script defer>` but no luck.